# Difference between is_int and is_integer php methods

Tags: php, methods

which is the difference between the php methods:

```
is_int()
```

and

```
is_integer()
```

?

Thanks!

Comment: The fact that they're spelled differently...

Answer (score 28):

There is none. [`is_integer`](https://www.php.net/is_integer) is an alias of [`is_int`](https://www.php.net/is_int), as stated on the [documentation page for `is_integer`](https://www.php.net/is_integer):

> `is_integer` — Alias of `is_int()`

Answer (score 15):

There is no difference, both `is_int()` and `is_integer()` are aliases of the `is_long()` function.

<sup>(This is one occasion where the documentation and source code diverge.)</sup>

---

The relevant *function entry* and *alias* declarations can be seen in the PHP source code (e.g. [in PHP 5.4](http://svn.php.net/viewvc/php/php-src/branches/PHP_5_4/ext/standard/basic_functions.c?view=markup#l3051)) like (reformatted for clarity):

`PHP_FE(is_long,                   arginfo_is_long)`

`PHP_FALIAS(is_int,      is_long,  arginfo_is_long)`

`PHP_FALIAS(is_integer,  is_long,  arginfo_is_long)`

Comment: Wow you're smarter than the other guy.

Answer (score 7):

is_integer — Alias of is_int()

is_int — Find whether the type of a variable is integer

Integers can be specified in decimal (base 10), hexadecimal (base 16), octal (base 8) or binary (base 2) notation, optionally preceded by a sign (- or +).